# determine the cost and time for every line of the code and calculate time complexity

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, recursion

I'm having difficulty finding the cost and time of these line of codes can anyone help me. I know the time complexity of merge-sort is generally **O (n log2 n)** but I'm having a hard time listing the time for each line like the cost of C1, C2, C3...

Code Snippet for Merge Sort Program

```
public class MergeSort {
    public static int[] mergeTwoSortedArrays(int[] one, int[] two) {
        int[] sorted = new int[one.length + two.length];
        int i, j, k = 0;

        while (i < one.length && j < two.length) {
            if (one[i] < two[j]) {
                sorted[k] = one[i];
                k++;
                i++;
            } else {
                sorted[k] = two[j];
                k++;
                j++;
            }
        }

        if (i == one.length) {
            while (j < two.length) {
                sorted[k] = two[j];
                k++;
                j++;
            }
        }

        if (j == two.length) {
            while (i < one.length) {
                sorted[k] = one[i];
                k++;
                i++;
            }
        }
        return sorted;
    }

    public static int[] mergeSort(int[] x, int left, int right) {
        if (left == right) {
            int[] br = new int[1];
            br[0] = x[left];
            return br;
        }

        int mid = (left + right) / 2;
        int[] fh = mergeSort(x, left, mid);
        int[] sh = mergeSort(x, mid + 1, right);
        int[] merged = mergeTwoSortedArrays(fh, sh);
        return merged;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should learn how to paste your code with proper indenting

Answer (score 1):

Hi when you call the function what you need to do is 
write this code and call the function.

```
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

    // start of function 
    // enter the values 
     mergeTwoSortedArrays(int[] one, int[] two) ; 

    // end of function 

    // ending time 
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    System.out.println("time taken by the function " + 
                                (end - start) + "ms");
```

do it same with the next function... hope so it will help you... 
and here is a link that will help you better

visit https://beyondcorner.com/calculate-time-complexity-algorithms-java-programs/

Comment: tnxs @bilal but I'm actually not trying to find/ print the time in ms. I'm trying to determine the best-case, worst case, and average-case by first manually finding how long it will take each line of code and multiplying it with some constant like c1, c2, c3 ... like this ==> https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceoAc.png